# Flink operators Benchmarking

Tags: apache-flink, benchmarking

I have a simple Flink job:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setParallelism(1);

    DataSet<String> lines = env.readTextFile(input_path);

    Dataset<String> words = env.flatMap(new LinesToWordFlatMap());

    Dataset<String> count = words.map(new mapFunct());

    Dataset<String> grouped = count.groupBy(new groupBy());

    Dataset<String> wordCount = grouped.reduce(new reduceFunct());


    wordCount.toDataSet().writeAsText(outputPath, FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE).setParallelism(1);

    try {
        env.execute("WordCount Example");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Now I would like to evaluate the execution time of each operator (flatMap, map, groupBy, reduce) individually. I tried with the [JMH](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html) library but I am not able to implement the logic for a Flink job.

I also had a look into this [repository](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-benchmarks), but I can not match one of the examples in it with my case.

Is there a simple way for individual operator benchmarking for execution time in Flink that could match with my use case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm curious what exactly you're trying to determine by measuring the execution time of each operator. Note, for example, that network time will often dominate. E.g. in your example, the amount of time various operators take should be small relative to time taken to partition data over the network (assuming parallelism > 1).

Comment: @kkrugler We are using this case a baseline for a research experiment. The idea is to micro-benchmarking Flink operators to see if there are consequences depending on different factors, like incremental throughput, different data sizes, etc..

Comment: Getting meaningful measurements is going to be difficult. I suggest you study https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-benchmarks (which uses jmh).

Comment: @DavidAnderson You are right that is why I am looking for meaningful solutions as you say. I had a look into the repository that you mention and I couldn't find a case where instead of measuring the whole Job execution metrics, it reach the measurements for each operator individually. But I will have a closer look. thanks

Comment: We compute per-operator costs by comparing results from running full pipelines that differ only slightly. E.g., run src -> sink, then run src -> map -> sink, etc. Arguably that tells us what we want to know, which is the cost of adding the additional operator to a pipeline. (BTW, groupBy isn't an operator -- it's a declaration that the operators before and after it are connected by a keyed network shuffle).

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks that could be an option